# having trouble passing form data using perl LWP lib

Tags: html, forms, perl, lwp

I am trying to use perl to automate login to a website and then have it click a link to get a certain data from my account.  here are the exact details:

1. go to www.bwsc.org and have it fill in the account info (account number and meter number)
2. submit form which will take me to a base account page
3. follow one of the links on this page to get specific account info

I keep getting stuck on the first steps. Perhaps I am going about this wrong, but I thought I could use the perl LWP lib to access the form data and fill in the info. As a first step, I looked at the relevant source html from www.bwsc.org to get the form info:

```
<div id="logonbox_SB">               
        <form action="/ACCOUNTS/security_main.asp" method="get">
        <div id="FS_1">
        <label for="AcctNum" id="acctnum_label">Account Number</label> 
        <input name="AcctNum" type="text" class="formtext1" size="9" maxlength="9" />
        </div>
        <div id="FS_2">
        <label for="MtrNum" id="accsnum_label">Access Number</label>
        <input name="MtrNum" type="text" class="formtext2" size="4" maxlength="4" />
        </div>
        <input type="image" value="Submit" name="search" class="boxsubmitbtn" src="/images/buttons/login.gif" alt="Login">
        </form>

        <p><a href="/ACCOUNTS/accounts.asp">Need help logging in?</a> </p>

</div><!--end logonbox_SB-->
```

The AcctNum and MtrNum text fields are the ones I need to fill in. Below is the code I wrote to try to do this:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use LWP::UserAgent;
use HTTP::Request::Common;

my ($ua, $request, $response, $content);
$ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;

$request = new HTTP::Request('GET','http://www.bwsc.org/ACCOUNTS/security_main.asp?AcctNum=XXX&MtrNum=XXX' );
$response = $ua->request($request);

my $content = $response->content;

open(FILE, ">out.txt");
print FILE $content;
close(FILE);
```

If I look at the output file out.txt (which I believe should contain the response html), it just gives me html for an error page saying I have not provided valid account info. I'm not really sure what I am doing wrong. I have tried various ways to pass parameters as suggested by the cpan docs, but no luck.

Some things to note:

1. The form in question doesn't have a name/id attribute (not sure if this matters)
2. The form is using the get method
3. The out.txt file containing the response html isn't the same as the html as that I receive when I intentionally login incorrectly using a browser. I mean that if I use the browser and don't enter any account info, the error page in the browser is not the same as the error page I receive when using this script.

Comment: You need to remove your account details from this post, right now!

Comment: Also, contact the site owners to get your account details removed from the edit history.

Comment: How ironic, `security_main.asp` with sensitive data in the query string.

Comment: Have you tried sniffing your HTTP traffic when doing the login from browser and from the script? How do the two cases differ? If you make exactly the same request from Perl and from your browser, the server must return the same response.

Comment: Also try appending `&search=Submit` to the URL. It is definitely sent from browser.

Answer (score 0):

Following code works in my project

```perl
use HTTP::Headers;
use LWP::UserAgent

my $headers = HTTP::Headers->new('Accept-Encoding' => 'gzip');

my $useragent = LWP::UserAgent->new(agent => 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/30.0.1599.114 Safari/537.36', timeout => 20, keep_alive => 100, default_headers => $headers );

my $url = 'http://www.bwsc.org/ACCOUNTS/security_main.asp?AcctNum=XXX&MtrNum=XXX';

my $response = $useragent->get($url);

my $content = $response->content;
```

Try it.

Comment: i got mine to work also by doing the following:

`$ua->cookie_jar( <br>
HTTP::Cookies->new(
file => 'mycookies.txt',`
autosave => 1
));`